# How can I interpret this YOLOV7 segmentation results plot?

Tags: classification, yolo, image-segmentation

I have the following results plot generated by train.py of YOLO-V7 segmentation:

[image]

The problem is that I am not sure how to interpret this plot. For example, to check for overfitting, I need information about the test and validation datasets, which is not available in the plot. Additionally, I don't understand why the precision of the mask turns to 0 in the last epoch consistently in several experiments.

Which aspects should I consider for my report, and how can I interpret them?
Thanks.